# Getting 'infinity' in apex charts series section

Tags: angular, typescript, apexcharts

My apex chart series block displays 'Infinity' when there is no series data.
I searched a lot for the solution but couldn't find any.
Attached is the picture below.

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

[apes.chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqgwg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please provide some relevant code that might lead to the problem, or better yet - reproduce the problem online (e.g via stackblitz). Problem could be anything at the moment but seeing that you get the chart rendered it's most likely not a problem with the chart, rather the data your feeding it.

For example `console.log(1 / 0)` would also print `Infinity`.

[Using Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity#using_infinity)

Comment: thanks for the help...fount out the problem...it occurs only when the data provided become zeroes.  I think there might be some kind of division performed to find out the series pattern in apex